# How to extract just the IN count of a Tableau set

Tags: tableau-api

How can I extract the IN count portion of a Tableau set?  I can see the IN/OUT counts when I drop the set into Text but can't figure out how to get at the IN value by itself.

Ultimately, I want to create a Pie Chart of three sets with just the IN counts as the measures.

I am using Tableau Public if that is a factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be a little careful about specifying what you wish to count.

One way to think of a set is as a Boolean function that gives a value to each data record denoting whether that record is associated with the set.

Another way to think of a set is as a mathematical set whose members are a subset of the values for some discrete field. (Or Tuple of fields)

The difference between the two views is really just a mindset, whether you consider the set as a Boolean function whose domain is a data row in the data source, or whose domain is the field on which the set definition is based.

Say you are looking at Tableau’s Superstore data set where each data record is a line item for a product attached to an order.

If your set is based on the field Region, say its called [My Favorite Regions] and currently contains {“East”, “Central”} do you want your count to be 2 (i.e. the number of regions in the set) ? Or do you want your count to be in the tens of thousands (i.e the number of line items on orders from the regions in the set)? Or something in between, maybe the number of distinct orders (i.e. order ids) within the selected regions...

If you want to count data rows that are associated with the set, you can simply filter by the set and calculate SUM([Number of Records[). If you want to count the regions in the set even though the level of detail of the data is at the order line item level,then you’ll have to use either a COUNTD to count the distinct regions, or some approach to specify what it is you want Tableau to count.

For example, put your set on the filter shelf, and show COUNTD(Region) which could be slow for very large data sets. To get the same effect without an explicit filter, you can define a LOD calculation such as:

```
{ COUNTD(if [My Favorite Regions] then [Region] end) }
```

Or you could use a table calc with the SIZE() function to do the calculation in the Tableau client instead of by the data source.

Comment: Excellent.  I will review what I'm trying to 'really' do and rethink it through.  This is very helpful to help me make sure I'm using sets with the right mentality.

Comment: This answer made me really think through what I was after.  I was able to use sets along with a filter to get what I wanted.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your data looks like but you could set a certain condition when creating a set or split the IN/OUT into two different sets.
Here's a [link to sets in Tableau](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/sortgroup_sets_create.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an if statement

```
IF [set] = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Then I suppose you could sum this calculated field

The most common usage is when you have a lot of categories and want to create an 'Other' category based on the categories that aren't in a set, if the set is a "Top N Set"

To do this:

```
IF [set] = TRUE THEN [dimension] ELSE 'Others' END
```

Comment: “[set] = TRUE” is redundant. You can just type “[set]”